# Неверная кодировка при записи

Tags: python, кодировка

При записи в файл записывает не кириллицей, как исправить?

```
array = ['Gthd', 'вторая']

with open('file1.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fw: #Записываем дополненный массив в файл
    json.dump(list(array), fw)
```

Получаем:

```
["Gthd", "\u0432\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0430\u044f"]
```

Comment: `json.dump(list(array), fw, ensure_ascii=False)`

Comment: Спасибо. Всё заработало.